# When can I use the expression "water off a duck's back"?

Tags: idioms

Would you please let me know more about this expression?

> 'Water off a duck's back'

I know this means that criticism or negative events have no effect on me, but it's not easy to use in real life. So if you can, please let me know more sentences that use the above.

Comment: You can find more examples [here](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Idioms/Quizzes/Animals_1/_like_water_off_a_duck_s_back_575.htm)

Comment: @Arrowfar :Thanks but it's closer to literal not real life. I just meant that the usage in daily life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Laugh all you like, it's water off a duck's back to me.*
*You can criticise and ridicule me all day, it's just like water off a duck's back to me.*

There are plenty more examples out there I'm sure but sufficed to say, you can use it whenever you wish to inform somebody that you are or were in no way bothered about what they said or did.